# How would I create an invert higher order function?

Tags: javascript, function, higher-order-functions

I need to create a higher-order function called invert. It should do the following:

Return a new function.
Take a function as its only argument.
The inner function should take any number of arguments and inverts a call to the passed function.

What I have so far is just http://prntscr.com/l0rma0 but it only works for functions with no arguments.

Comment: Please post code here as code, not as a link to an image. While you're at it, your opinion here would be helpful: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374700/476

Comment: What do you expect as your output when you did `!func`

Comment: I expected it to just inverse the function passed through function invert(func) {
  return function() {
    return !func;
  };
}

Comment: Can you explain the concept of *function inverse*

Comment: What do you mean by inverting function !?

Comment: Write a higher-order function called invert.

It should do the following:

It should return a new function.
It should take a function as its only argument.
The inner function should take any number of arguments and inverts a call to the passed function

Everything I have.

Comment: @Robin this higher order function will take a function like isSumBiggerThan100 and turn it to isSumLessThanOrEqualTo100,  i cant find a similar solution online

Comment: @rv7 this higher order function will take a function like isSumBiggerThan100 and turn it to isSumLessThanOrEqualTo100,  i cant find a similar solution online

Comment: @AlexKeeley Please include a working example in your post of what you're saying

Comment: @rv7 it("invert works for functions taking any number of arguments", () => {
    const isSumBiggerThan100 = function(...args) {
      return args.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val) > 100;
    };
    const isSumLessThanOrEqualTo100 = invert(isSumBiggerThan100);
    actual = isSumLessThanOrEqualTo100(10, 3, 8, 5, 4, 20);
    expect(actual).to.be.true;
    actual = isSumLessThanOrEqualTo100(70, 10, 50, 23);
    expect(actual).to.be.false;
  });

function should pass these tests, i dont know how else to explain it, it confuses me as well

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, this should be enough:

```
function invert(fn) {
  return (...args) => !fn(...args);
}
```

Here's the test case:

```js
function invert(fn) {
  return (...args) => !fn(...args);
}

// test 1
const returnsTrue = () => true;
const returnsFalse = invert(returnsTrue);

console.log( returnsFalse() === false );

// test 2
const isEven = x => x % 2 === 0;
const isOdd = invert(isEven);

console.log( isOdd(13) === true );
console.log( isOdd(10) === false );

// test 3
const isSumBiggerThan100 = (...args) => args.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val) > 100;
const isSumLessThanOrEqualTo100 = invert(isSumBiggerThan100);

console.log( isSumLessThanOrEqualTo100(10, 3, 8, 5, 4, 20) === true);
console.log( isSumLessThanOrEqualTo100(70, 10, 50, 23) === false)
```

Comment: Thank you! I always understand them when they're displayed but I am struggling to create them. thanks a lot

Comment: It takes time to get confident with higher-order functions / combinators. Glad it helped.

Comment: @AlexKeeley On a side note, would you mind accepting the answer if you found it satisfactory?

Answer (score -1):

```
const higherFunction = (something) => {
  return function innerFunc(...params) {
    return !something;
  }
};
```

Do you mean something like that ?

Comment: Yes like that but I still get false instead of true for it  http://prntscr.com/l0s4rg   too much to type, these are my test cases needed to pass